# Debuggin Python curses program

Tags: python, curses

Im writing a Python curses program using vi editor. Would like to understand how to debug the module to debug it?

Is there any tools that I can use?

Comment: There's PDB, the Python debugger...

Comment: Well, once you understand how to debug the module, you will understand how to debug the module to debug it. Proof by induction. :)

Comment: Anyway, you can debug it in any of the same ways you can debug any other Python program—run it in a debugger, insert `logging` statements, extract parts of the program to unit test, etc.—except for simple `print`.

Comment: @MattDMo pdb doesn't work with curses, because curses changes the stdin reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To easily debug a `curses` program, you can use `curses.wrapper` like this:

```
import curses
def make_me_an_error(screen, numerator, denominator):
    screen.addstr(0, 0, str(numerator/denominator)) # divide by zero

curses.wrapper(make_me_an_error, 1, 0)
```

Upon return or exception from `make_me_an_error`, wrapper automatically cleans up the screen and restores it to its original settings

From [wrapper docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper):

> Initialize curses and call another callable object, func, which should
>   be the rest of your curses-using application. If the application
>   raises an exception, this function will restore the terminal to a sane
>   state before re-raising the exception and generating a traceback. The
>   callable object func is then passed the main window ‘stdscr’ as its
>   first argument, followed by any other arguments passed to wrapper().
>   Before calling func, wrapper() turns on cbreak mode, turns off echo,
>   enables the terminal keypad, and initializes colors if the terminal
>   has color support. On exit (whether normally or by exception) it
>   restores cooked mode, turns on echo, and disables the terminal keypad.